# spring boot application exception

Tags: spring-boot

i am trying to run a simple spring boot application but unable to run it . please help . this is my main file , pom.xml and error

[Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od17t.png)

[Main Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySFgS.png)

**stack trace:**

```
2019-01-26 12:43:11.619  INFO 17684 --- [           main] c.w.service.service.ServiceApplication   : Starting ServiceApplication on DESKTOP-T03T8BR with PID 17684 (D:\hello\service\target\classes started by Nexus in D:\hello\service)
2019-01-26 12:43:11.624  INFO 17684 --- [           main] c.w.service.service.ServiceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-26 12:43:11.775  INFO 17684 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2d2e5f00: startup date [Sat Jan 26 12:43:11 PKT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-26 12:43:13.912  INFO 17684 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4eba9b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-26 12:43:13.942  WARN 17684 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
2019-01-26 12:43:13.958  INFO 17684 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-26 12:43:13.977 ERROR 17684 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:226) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.web.service.service.ServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.<clinit>(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:66) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.initDefaultStrategies(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:107) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:98) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractActionEndpointMapping.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.java:34) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.<init>(AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.java:60) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.annotationActionEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:120) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4eba9b.CGLIB$annotationActionEndpointMapping$4(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4eba9b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d551914b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4eba9b.annotationActionEndpointMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.xml.DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

please help.

Comment: Sounds like a missing dependency

Comment: Please post your code as text. It's hard to copy/paste from images.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle add dependency

```
compile"org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:${springWsCoreVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something in your application.properies file? Have you tried to remove jpa and h2 dependencies from the pom and start the application? :)

Here is a hint for you. I think you should make some entities and fill them with values.
Check out this link:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/